# Como formular un UPDATE con datos de otro registro. MYSQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

Necesito ACTUALIZAR todos los registros de una tabla con otro registro de la misma, pero con solo algunos caracteres.

```
Tabla 1
_______
id
nombre
num
tipo
```

Requiero que cada uno de los registros que esta en el campo **num**, pase al campo **tipo**, pero solamente los primeros 10 caracteres, obtengo los 10 caracteres en el siguiente codigo

```
SELECT SUBSTR(num,1,10) FROM tabla1
```

**num**: 1234567890AB

**tipo**: AB

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que quieres realizar un `UPDATE`, con el código que tienes casi lo tienes resuelto:

```
UPDATE tabla1 SET tipo = SUBSTR(num,1,10)
```

Actualizará todas las filas de la `tabla1` poniendo en el campo `tipo` los diez primeros caracteres del campo `num`.